# I need some orientation about ROS

Tags: ros, rosjava, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm starting learning ROS, because I have bought a drone and I want to programme it. My purpose is to develop a simple interface with Java, where I can send instructions to the drone (arm, takeoff, change flight mode,...) and I've read that I should use the MAVLink protocol to communicate with it.

Reading in the forums, I think that I should use ROS (maybe mavros or rosjava), but I'm not sure if it is a good way to achieve my purpose or not.

I would like to read your opinions because I'm a bit lost.

Thank you all!

Edit: I think that I should use ROS instead ROSJava, but I need the libraries like "ros/ros.h" and "std_msgs/String.h", to use in Java. Do you know what libraries should I use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245463/i-need-some-orientation-about-ros/) by [Antolinos95](https://answers.ros.org/users/28212/antolinos95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-10-14**:
I have no real answer for you and I have never tried ROSJava, but as far as I see it ROSJava does not come even close to C++ and Python in terms of available packages. While there is plenty of documentation and tutorials for c++ and python, for ROSJava there is very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this thread: https://discourse.ros.org/t/is-rosjava-worth-using-when-not-using-android/1967/11.

In short, if you are a Java developer and what you need to do is relatively simple (e.g. sending instructions using a publisher with standard or custom messages), I would suggest you to try rosjava. The basic tutorial entry point is https://wiki.ros.org/rosjava.
As Dimitri says in the comment, you will probably find more packages in roscpp and rospy, so if you need packages that already exist maybe that would be a better solution for you.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0